# Flash Gets Blocked By ISP

Tags: php, mysql, html, flash

I have developed a set of flash games which are being used by several schools across the UK. For some odd reason, the school cannot seem to load the Flash games....

Upon contacting the ISP (SWGFL) - I was told that the network would automatically block flash games. This is all well and good BUT the school in question is able to load the following flash game:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbbc/games/deadly-scramble-game

I am currently using a PHP layer to communicate between Flash and a MySQL database. I was wondering if anyone knew any reasons as to why this might occur? Is there some kind of header() protocol I need to add to bypass this flash blocking?

This happens in IE FF & Safari (other browsers have not been tested).

Comment: You need to find someone at the ISP that can actually help you. BBC probably has a firewall exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to use HTTPS, since the data will be encrypted as its transferred to the browser and requests to the server are encrypted, the ISP won't be able to determine that there is a flash game and the school should be able to run the game just fine as long as the browsers themselves are not configured to block flash content.